# ES6 Destructuring and check a parametre

Tags: javascript

```
    const data = { 
    
    countries: [
        {
          id: 'france',
          name: 'France',
          europe: true,
          cities: [
            'Paris',     'Lyon',  'Metz',
            'Bourdeaux',    'Marsielle',  'Nantes',
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 'italy',
          name: 'Italy',
          europe: true,
          cities: [
            'Rome',   'Milan',
            'Torino',   'Napoli',
          ]
        },
    }
```

I'm trying to create a function with 2 parameters, first one will be data and the second is a city name, I need an example with reduce to check if the second parameter exist in the cities and if yes, return country.name.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: A simple `for` loop + `.includes()` or `.indexOf()` would do the job. Or use `.find()`, ...

Comment: please provide expected input and output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function to iterate over countries.

**Example:**

```js
    function getCountry(data, city) {
      return data.countries.reduce((result, country) => {
        if (country.cities.includes(city)) {
          return country.name;
        }
        return result;
      }, null);
    }
    
    const data = {
      countries: [
        {
          id: 'france',
          name: 'France',
          europe: true,
          cities: [
            'Paris',     'Lyon',  'Metz',
            'Bourdeaux',    'Marsielle',  'Nantes',
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 'italy',
          name: 'Italy',
          europe: true,
          cities: [
            'Rome',   'Milan',
            'Torino',   'Napoli',
          ]
        },
      ]
    };
    
    console.log(getCountry(data, 'Paris')); // Output: "France"
    console.log(getCountry(data, 'Milan')); // Output: "Italy"
    console.log(getCountry(data, 'New York')); // Output: null
```

Comment: `.reduce()` doesn't make much sense. If there's a city that is in more than one country your solution will always return the latter. Why not the first? Or second? Why iterate over all countries if you've already found the city?

Comment: `If there's a city that is in more than one country your solution will always return the latter. ` OP could return value after the first with `return`

Comment: You have two `return`s...